# Border Top Half length

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have attached an Image. I want to create similar Border. but I am unable to create top border half

here is my CSS

```
border-left:1px solid;
border-top:1px solid;
border-bottom:1px solid;
border-right:1px solid;
```

How do I actually make top border limited?

Comment: You can't. You need to put above the icon with a background to achieve the effect, but the borders will render always 100%

Comment: anyway I can do this?

Comment: Not possible to "clip" a border. Put the border around the entire box - then use positioning to position the logo (and its oversized clip) over top of the border. It will create this illusion so long as the "whitespace" of your logo is the same color as your page background.

Comment: I tell you, you must to put the icon with the grey background, to cover the piece of border. Easy. Just `.icon { position: absolute; top: -30px; background-color: #888; }` give the right values and it's ready to work

Comment: If you use Marcos' suggestion you'll also need to have a `position` property on the parent element set to a value other than `static` (the default). Incidentally if you post your ("*[MCVE]*") HTML you'll get a specifically useful, rather than hypothetical, answer to your question.

Comment: There is a way. Working on a solution now.

Comment: You could use a fieldset/legend https://jsfiddle.net/2twn9kjg/

Answer (score 3):

You can abuse a `fieldset` and `legend` for this:

```css
fieldset {
  height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
legend {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Icon here</legend>
</fieldset>
```

**Note**: This is **not** semantic as this is not the intended use of a `fieldset` or `legend`.

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)

> The HTML  element is used to group several controls as well as labels () within a web form.

Comment: I don't know, but I think that is because depending on the browser the fieldset will render different. And if OP use bootstrap it's poor, because the fieldsets are totally changed by design.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the down-vote, in addition to the issues raised by Marcos, might be due to the 'abuse' of the elements used; I can honestly say that, looking at this (admittedly-working) solution I shudder inside, despite being unable to offer anything better (given the lack of HTML provided by the OP).

Answer (score 1):

Use fieldset and legend:

```css
body {
  background-color: #4a494e;
}

.box {
  border: 5px #b79a60 solid;
  color: #b79a60;
}

.box-label {
  color: #b79a60;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="box">
  <legend class="box-label">Insert Clock Image Here</legend>
  <h1>Hours</h1>
  <p>Show gallery opens daily</p>
  <p>11.00am - 6.00pm</p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D beat me to the punch